# Grid: How to prevent row deselection on hit Enter?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

My grid uses `CheckboxModel` and `CellEditing` plugin. When the user types something in a field and hits `Enter` button, then I see that checkmark disappears from the first ckeckbox column. But at the same time `getSelectionModel().getSelection()` shows, that one row is still selected. This behaviour is quite weird and may confuse ordinary users. So, I need some workaround.

Here is a picture of what is going on. Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

As you can see, there is no longer checkmark in the first column and no selected records, but `getSelection()` still shows one record being selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After enter you could try fetching the record you had edited and use grid.getSelectionModel().select(record, true, false)